# JSON encode GEO.Point from geo library as human readable form

Tags: ecto, geo, elixir, elixir-poison

I have this schema which has a [Geo](https://github.com/bryanjos/geohttps://github.com/bryanjos/geo) `Geo.Point`:

```
defmodule Api.Shop do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Api.Repo
  import Ecto.Query

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :place_id, :geo_json, :distance]}
  schema "shops" do
    field :name, :string
    field :place_id, :string
    field :point, Geo.Point
    field :geo_json, :string, virtual: true
    field :distance, :float, virtual: true

    timestamps()
  end

  def encode_model(shop) do
    %Api.Shop{shop | geo_json: Geo.JSON.encode(shop.point) }
  end

  defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Api.Shop do
    def encode(shop, options) do
      shop = Api.Shop.encode_model(shop)
      Poison.Encoder.Map.encode(Map.take(shop, [:id, :name, :geo_json]), options)
    end
  end

  def changeset(shop, params \\ %{}) do
    shop
    |> cast(params, [:name, :place_id, :point])
    |> validate_required([:name, :place_id, :point])
    |> unique_constraint(:place_id)
  end......
end
```

And when I return the `shop.point` field in a query:

```
  def create_query_no_keyword(categories, shop_ids) do
    products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
    distinct: p.id,
    join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
    join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
    join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
    join: c in Subcategory, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
    where: c.id in ^categories,
    where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
    group_by: [p.id, p.name, p.brand],
    select: %{product: p, categories: fragment("json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?)) AS category", c.id, c.name), shops: fragment("json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?, ?)) AS shop", s.id, s.name, s.point)}
  end
```

What gets returned is actually `0101000020E6100000A3BDB0EB0DD9654030AC2C1BE76D42C0` which is the wrong format - WKB. I'm looking to encode as WKT which has readable coordinates.

How do I get `s.point` to be `WKT` format and thus have coordinates, when it is returned by the query?

Comment: How about `"01..." |> Geo.WKB.decode |> Geo.WKT.encode`?

Comment: @Dogbert Just wondering where I write that code?

Comment: Can you post the output of `IO.inspect(create_query_no_keyword(categories, shop_ids) |> Api.Repo.all)`? It's not completely clear to me where that WKB value is in the returned value.

Comment: @Dogbert Just did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this Stack Exchange GIS answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42971) to be the solution:

> use this for point object:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) 
       FROM myTable; and viewing X,Y and geom object:

SELECT ST_X(the_geom), ST_Y(the_geom), ST_AsText(the_geom) 
       FROM myTable;
```

The [Geo](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo) library is using [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) and the solution was PostGIS specific. You need to select the column using `ST_AsText`, or `ST_X` and `ST_Y` from PostGIS.

My select statement changed to this:

```
select: %{product: p, categories: fragment("json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?)) AS category", c.id, c.name), shops: fragment("json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?, ST_X(?), ST_Y(?))) AS shop", s.id, s.name, s.point, s.point)}
```